# PHP, MySQL Table UPDATE issue

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, sql-update

Am trying to UPDATE a innodb table "products" by using a form of which last column is subid(fk) reference to table "subcategory" subid(PK), but i only want to update the "products" table without making any changes to subid(fk) column in "products" table, here is my full code

```
<?php   

if (isset($_POST['PRODUCT_NAME'])) {

$pid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['thisPID']);
$catalog_no = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['CATALOG_NO']);
$product_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['PRODUCT_NAME']);
$price = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['PRICE']);
$composition = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['COMPOSITION']);
$size = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['SIZE']);
// See if that product name is an identical match to another product in the system
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE products SET CATALOG_NO='$catalog_no', PRODUCT_NAME='$product_name', PRICE='$price', COMPOSITION='$composition', SIZE='$size' WHERE PID='$pid'") or die(mysql_error());
header("location: inventory_list.php"); 
exit();  
}
?> 

<?php 
if (isset($_GET['PID'])) {
$targetID = $_GET['PID'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT products.PID, products.CATALOG_NO, products.PRODUCT_NAME, products.PRICE, products.COMPOSITION, products.SIZE FROM products WHERE PID='$targetID' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 

         $catalog_no = $row["CATALOG_NO"];
         $product_name = $row["PRODUCT_NAME"];
         $price = $row["PRICE"];
         $composition = $row["COMPOSITION"];
         $size = $row["SIZE"];
    }
} else {
    echo "You dont have that product";
    exit();
}
}
?>
```

The form uses the following code

```
<form action="inventory_edit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" id="myform" method="post">
<table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
  <tr>
    <td width="20%" align="right">Product Name</td>
    <td width="80%"><label>
      <input name="product_name" type="text" id="product_name" size="64" value="<?php echo $product_name; ?>" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Product Price</td>
    <td><label>
      $
      <input name="price" type="text" id="price" size="12" value="<?php echo $price; ?>" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Composition</td>
    <td><label>
      <textarea name="composition" id="composition" cols="64" rows="5"><?php echo $composition; ?></textarea>
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Size</td>
    <td><label>
      <input type="text" name="size" id="size" value="<?php echo $size; ?>" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>      
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><label>
      <input name="thisID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $targetID; ?>" />
      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Make Changes" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

The form does nothing (it just refreshes the page), it does not UPDATE the table. How to solve this problem?

Here is my table structure: table name - "products" set to ON UPDATE and ON DELETE CASCADE

```
PID(PK) CATALOG_NO  PRODUCT_NAME PRICE COMPOSITION SIZE SUBCAT_ID(FK)
  1         bbp2         NO2      $45    1% NO     10ml      7
```

Comment: yeah...it's hard to debug a problem when we don't know what it is. Is it a logic problem? a syntax problem? et cetera..

Comment: the problem is that form does nothing it just refreshes the page and do not update the table with the changes am doing using the form

Comment: @henry Try removing the redirection `header("location: inventory_list.php"); ` Then you should be able to see the errors. It is also useful to echo the SQL that you send to MySQL to that you can check that it is actually valid after the parameters have been replaced.

Comment: @MarvinLabs  removing redirection results the same, no changes on pressing "make changes" button of the form it does notihng, just refreshes the page and no entries are updated

Comment: What you need are tools that can help you analyse the problem.  Firebug or something similar to see the request.  Check your web server logs to see it received it.  Echo debug information from your script to see what is happening with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$pid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['thisPID']);
```

Here you have missed out the `<input name="thisID" type="hidden">`.It should be `thisPID`.

Comment: Made changes in the input tag, still the same results, it just refreshes values unchanged, doesnt update the table

Comment: there are no sql errors shown, am putting up the table structure

Comment: I have put the table structure

Answer (score 0):

Debug your code like this submit your form & check each value

// See if that product name is an identical match to another product in the system
echo $sql = "UPDATE products SET CATALOG_NO='$catalog_no', PRODUCT_NAME='$product_name', PRICE='$price', COMPOSITION='$composition', SIZE='$size' WHERE PID='$pid'";

exit;

Comment: @user692487 debugging does not help, result is same

Comment: only  echo  this ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: echo $sql = "UPDATE products SET CATALOG_NO='$catalog_no', PRODUCT_NAME='$product_name', PRICE='$price', COMPOSITION='$composition', SIZE='$size' WHERE PID='$pid'";  exit;

Answer (score 0):

Since the query doesn't seem to be doing anything, but isn't triggering an error condition (or you'd see it via the `die()` call, you should check to see exactly what the generated query string looks like:

```
$sql = "UPDATE products SET CATALOG_NO='$catalog_no', PRODUCT_NAME='$product_name', PRICE='$price', COMPOSITION='$composition', SIZE='$size' WHERE PID='$pid'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

echo $sql;
```

Just because the query call didn't do the `die()` doesn't mean the query is valid. Examine the generated query, try to run it manually, see what happens then.

Comment: @Marc B Hi, thanks for your suggestion Marc, but the result is same echo $sql does not show up anything

Comment: yes does not show anything, and also just refreshes the page on clicking "submit" button

Comment: Did you change it the version I showed above? or are you still doing `$sql = mysql_query(...);`? You need to preserve the SQL statement you're generating. Otherwise you're just outputting the return value of `mysql_query()`

Comment: @Marc B If you want I can give you access, you can login yourself n can see whats happening

Comment: @Marc B I copy pasted your code above mine, I changed it as per your instruction

Comment: Then something is very weird. At minimum you should see the query's text. what happens if you change `$sql` to be something invalid like `$sql = "this will not work"` and run that through mysql_query()?

Comment: @Marc B after using $sql = "this will not work" also does not nothing the only change is that link changes from /inventory_edit.php?PID=1 to /inventory_edit.php after clicking the submit button of the form

Comment: I'd suggest disabling all the redirects in there. you should get SOME kind of output with that bad query.

Comment: no redirects are, i removed them first time itself when i copy pasted your code

Comment: Then something is very very weird. you should get SOME KIND OF OUTPUT. You've hardcoded a string into `$sql` and are outputting `$sql`, and nothing's showing up. So... you have to figure out why. Until you can see exactly what the query string you're generating is, anything else is just guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I did a mysql_query, but is this line correct?

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE products SET CATALOG_NO='$catalog_no', PRODUCT_NAME='$product_name', PRICE='$price', COMPOSITION='$composition', SIZE='$size' WHERE PID='$pid'") or die(mysql_error());
```

THis looks like it is writing the SQL as this

```
"UPDATE products SET CATALOG_NO='$catalog_no'"
```

instead of the value of $catalog_no.

Should the line not be constructed like this:

```
"UPDATE products SET CATALOG_NO='" . $catalog_no . "', PRODUCT_NAME='" . $product_name . '"...
```

etc..?